# When using SQLite under what conditions is it advised to use a deferred transaction?

Tags: ios, sqlite

It seems like a deferred transaction would be potentially dangerous if you have more than one database connection that may also try to obtain a lock for a transaction.  Is there other steps you should take when using a deferred transaction, like ensuring all transactions are deferred on the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deferred transactions can result in a deadlock if two connections read and then try to write; one transaction has to be aborted in this case.

To avoid this, all transactions that might do writes should be immediate transactions.

(Deferred transactions are the default because most applications do not use concurrent connections and use transactions only as protection against interruptions.)

Comment: Isn't the deadlock solved by timeout ? Like detailed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55831645/how-does-sqlite-prevent-deadlocks-with-deferred-transactions

Comment: @Liviu Getting a timeout error is usually not considered a useful solution. Retrying the entire transaction so far is possible only when the software has been written to support this.