# How does SQLite prevent deadlocks with deferred transactions?

Tags: sqlite

According to the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) on deferred ransactions:

> The default transaction behavior is deferred. (...) The first read operation against a database creates a SHARED lock and
>   the first write operation creates a RESERVED lock.

Also according to the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) on locks:

> Any number of processes can hold SHARED locks at the same time (...)
>   Only a single RESERVED lock may be active at one time, though multiple
>   SHARED locks can coexist with a single RESERVED lock

This sounds like a multiple readers/single writer lock with arbitrary reader-to-writer promotion mechanism, which is known to be a deadlock hazard:

- A starts transaction
- B starts transaction
- A acquires SHARED lock and reads something
- B acquires SHARED lock and reads something
- A acquires RESERVED lock and prepares to write something. It can't write as long as there are other SHARED locks so it blocks.
- B wishes to write so tries to take RESERVED lock. There is already another RESERVED lock so it blocks until it is released, still holding the SHARED lock.
- Deadlock.

So how does SQLite get around this? Two possible solutions come to my mind, but both of them seem to break the whole idea of a transaction:

- Would-be writers release the SHARED locks before acquiring RESERVED. This would break atomicity between reads and writes.
- B doesn't block when trying to take a RESERVED lock, but errors-out. This would mean all the reads would need to be repeated and significantly complicates API usage.

Am I missing something? How does SQLite deal with this? Why would this seemingly dangerous type of transaction be the default?

Comment: You forgot to address the use of PENDING locks, which very often break your deadlock scenario.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield How exactly? It's just a transition to EXCLUSIVE. In my example scenario, *A* technically transitioned from RESERVED to PENDING before blocking until it can transition to EXCLUSIVE.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield AFAIK, PENDING only solves the problem of writer starvation when faced with heavy readers, not deadlocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By simple trial and error, I discovered that they took the error-out route.

In the given scenario, when B tries to take RESERVED, it will first wait for `PRAGMA busy_timeout` milliseconds. Then it will report `Error: database is locked`. The transaction will still be active, so an immediate retry is possible.

If A afterwards tries to `COMMIT` (or if it runs out of in-memory cache), it will take the PENDING lock (preventing additional SHARED locks) and then wait for EXCLUSIVE. If some SHARED locks remain after `PRAGMA busy_timeout` milliseconds, it will report *Error: database is locked*. The transaction will still be active, so an immediate retry is possible.

In other words, the deadlock prevention mechanism in use is timeout. However, it does require the API users to cooperate by rolling back and trying again.

As a guideline:

- Use just `BEGIN TRANSACTION` (or explicitly `BEGIN DEFERRED TRANSACTION`) when you only expect to read. Writes could possibly fail, forcing you to rollback and retry the entire transaction again.
- Use `BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION` when you expect to maybe write at some point. This will block all other writers and all other immediate maybe-writers.
- `BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION` will immediately block until all other locks are released. I have no idea why anyone would want this. Possibly to prepare for some data which needs to be written to disk as quickly as possible once it arrives? **EDIT:** It seems to be the only way to prevent timeouts at arbitrary points after beginning a transaction.